# CSS Image having border-bottom when I don't want to

Tags: html, css

made a sort-of custom underline in my html site using

```
a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

but this also appears on images with links, how can I stop this. (also if this is a dumb question sorry I'm new)

Comment: Are your "images with links" just something like `<a><img /></a>` ?

Comment: It’s helpful if you could provide a working snippet so we can see the relevant HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be to apply class to your a tag.

```css
a.simple-link:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="simple-link" href="">Link</a>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <a href="" class="nested-link">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </a>
</div>
```